# How to check date and time of max values in large data set Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, max

I have data sets that are ~30-60,000,000 lines each. Each `Name` has **one or more** unique `ID` associated with it for every day in the data set. Some `OP_DATE` and `OP_HOUR` the unique IDs can have 0 or blank values for each `Load1,2,3`.

I'm looking for a way to calculate the **total** maximum values of columns over all the `OP_DATE` that look like these:

```
Name       ID       OP_DATE      OP_HOUR    OP_TIME     Load1       Load2     Load3
OMI        1        2001-01-01   1          1           11          10        12
OMI        1        2001-01-01   2          0.2         1           12        10
.
.
OMI        2A      2001-01-01    1          0.4                     5
.
. 
OMI        2A      2001-01-01    24         0.6         2            7        12
.
.
Kain 2     01      2002-01-01    1          0.1         6           12
Kain 2     01      2002-01-01    2          0.98        3           14        7
.
.
OMI        1       2018-01-01    1          0.89        12           10        20
.
.
```

I want to find the **maximum** values of `Load1`, `Load2`, `Load3`, and find what `OP_DATE`, `OP_TIME` and `OP_HOUR` that it occurred on.

The output I want is:

```
Name    ID    max OP_DATE   max OP_HOUR  max OP_TIME    max Load1   max Load2   max Load3
OMI     1     2011-06-11    22 .....         max values on dates
OMI     2A    2012-02-01    12 .....         max values on dates
Kain 2  01    2006-01-01    1.....           max values on dates
```

Is there a way I can do this easily?

I've tried:

```
unique_MAX =  df.groupby(['Name','ID'])['Load1', 'Load2', 'Load3'].max().reset_index()
```

But this would group only by the dates and give me a total maximum - I'd like the associated dates, hours, and times as well.

Comment: Just so I understand, for each `['Name','ID', 'OP_DATE']`, you need to find the row where the maximum across all of the Load columns occurs?

Comment: For each `Name` and `ID` I need a maximum value over all `OP_DATE` for `Load 1 2 and 3` and which `OP_DATE`, `OP_HOUR`, and `OP_TIME` those maximum values correspond to.

Comment: So you may need a different format `DataFrame`. With each Name, ID, each `Load` can have a different OP date for the maximum value, so you may need to go from your wide format to a long format, otherwise you wind up storing lists or the format becomes unintuitive

Answer (score 0):

**To get the full row of information for any given fields [max]**:

- Get the index locations for the max of each group you desire
- Use the indexes to return the full row at each location

---

**An example for finding the max Load1 for each Name & ID pair**

```
idx = df.groupby(['Name','ID'])['Load1'].transform(max) == df['Load1']
df[idx]

Out[14]: 
    name   ID        dt  x  y
1   Fred  050  1/2/2018  2  4
4   Dave  001  1/3/2018  6  1
5  Carly  002  1/3/2018  5  7
```